# "Das ist doch Marlene!"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Can someone tell me how the following two sentences differ?

> Das ist doch Marlene!
>
> Das ist Marlene!

Comment: "But that is Marlene! " vs. "That is Marlene!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This *doch* is either a modal particle or an adverb.

> Das ist doch **Marlene**! (particle, surprised about Marlene's presence)
>
> Das ist **doch** Marlene! (adverb, indicating someone identified the person wrong before)

The difference between the two can be told by the stress.

Without the *doch* the sentence is a plain identification.

> Das ist nicht Helene. Das ist Marlene.